# Watching service object for changes is not working when using the controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs

I tried to follow along with this example but my code never enters the callback with the `newValue` when the input changes for some reason. The only difference in my example and the example bin below is that I'm using a service to hold the value instead of a controller variable.

I've been trying to make it work but I can't wrap my head around it. What am I missing?

http://jsbin.com/yinadoce/1/edit?html,js,output

Note that I've excluded the input and the steps prior to the value being updated in the service as this works perfect. The issue is only that my watch doesn't understand when the value has changed in the service.

**EDIT:** Forgot to inject `$scope` in the controller when I pasted over the code, now it's complete.

Controller:

```
coForms.controller('CoFormsCtrl', ['$scope', 'coFormsInfo', function($scope, coFormsInfo) {

  $scope.$watch(angular.bind(coFormsInfo.getInfo(), function() {
    return coFormsInfo.getInfo();
  }), function(newVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
  });
}]);
```

Service:

```
coForms.service('coFormsInfo', [function() {

    var info = {
        filteredList: []
    }

    this.setFilteredList = function(list) {
        info.filteredList = list;
    };

    this.getInfo = function() {
        return info;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The watcher is there to detect any changes in the variable you're watching. How can he watch something that is not... Strictly present like a return value?

I'm not sure about what I'm saying because I'm new to angular, but the logic seems false there. You need to watch something declared to detect some changes.

You should call your service to get your infos when you need them and watch for an `info` variable.

**EDIT**

My bad there is something like that but you should declare it in a function maybe like the example on the documentation

```
var food;
scope.foodCounter = 0;
expect(scope.foodCounter).toEqual(0);
scope.$watch(
  // This function returns the value being watched. It is called for each turn of the $digest loop
  function() { return food; },
  // This is the change listener, called when the value returned from the above function changes
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
      // Only increment the counter if the value changed
      scope.foodCounter = scope.foodCounter + 1;
    }
  }
);
```